# Admin Order “Purchased From” always shown in the same Store View

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, admin

I have a problem installing Magento 1.7.0.2. All the orders placed from my customers are registered under the same (default) store view.

I have 3 websites and 2 store views for each. Everything seems to working fine for all the websites/storeviews except this problem about registering an order under the same website.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Change in below file path to static name

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\info.phtml
```

Or create new system config field and replace this below code to your system config code

```
<?php echo $this->getOrderStoreName() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow above @HarikaranK mentioned instruction

Here the code for system config to replace dynamically

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('section_name/group_name/field_name');?>
```